# Overriding the embed_key in Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer with some `has_many` associations where I've modified the `embed_key`.

I'm trying to have the IDs for my model be like `path-name` rather than `12`. The code below is making that happen:

```
class SymbolSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes  :id,
              :name,
              :parent_id,
              :rails_id

  embed :ids, include: true
  has_many  :ancestors, embed_key: :symbol_path, serializer: SimplifiedSymbolSerializer
  has_many  :children,  embed_key: :symbol_path, serializer: SimplifiedSymbolSerializer
  has_one   :parent,    embed_key: :symbol_path, serializer: SimplifiedSymbolSerializer
  has_many  :siblings,  embed_key: :symbol_path, serializer: SimplifiedSymbolSerializer

  def id
    object.symbol_path
  end

  def parent_id
    object.id
  end

  def rails_id
    object.id
  end
end
```

The problem is that I'd like to still have the actual `id` of the parent object *(Which I've tried to do in my `parent_id` method ^^)*.

Right now the overridden method still returns the `:symbol_path` key rather than the `id`.

Anyone know how to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way for me to address this was to just use a different naming convention for the key I wanted to pass.

So all I had to do was add this method/attribute in there too:

```
  def parent_rails_id
    object.parent.id
  end
```